# Quick complex number proof question:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

How would I go about proving the following identity:

$$\frac{1}{\left|z\right|} = \left|\frac{1}{z}\right|$$

I keep finding myself going in circles. I've tried using this identity: $|z|^2 = z^*z$ conjugate.

Comment: Exponential form of complex number.

Comment: @Gina is that the "e^(i*theta)" form?

Comment: The left side is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$. To compute the right side, try writing $z=a+bi$ and then computing $1/z$. Hint: multiply the numerator and denominator by $a-bi$. (If you have polar coordinates available, however, this problem is very simple.)

Comment: $z=re^{i\theta}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Remember that for complex numbers $a$ and $b$, $|a\cdot b| = |a|\cdot|b|$.  Based on this, what can we say about $\left|z\cdot \frac{1}{z} \right|$?

Comment: Great hint! Figured it out.